# WCF - can't access to MEX via browser

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I've just created new project "WCF Service Library" with almost default config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8734/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" /> -->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity><dns value="localhost" /></identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It runs perfectly in WcfSvcHost, but when I try to access to http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex via browser (Edge or Firefox) I get HTTP Error 400.

WCF Test Client works fine with that URI.

I tried to add "name" attribute to behavior tag and then using this name in service tag - didn't help.

Surprisingly I can fix it only when commented the following string:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

When address in WCF Test Client changed to: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1**?wsdl**

and this URI works fine in browser. But I think it's not a right way.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and.Net Framework 4.5.2 on Windows 10 x64 machine.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPD. Just to be clear: I want to see in browser my service page (starting with text "You have created a service"). When I removed "mex" endpoint I can just see .wsdl file - it's not what I want.

Comment: where do you declare your `mexHttpBinding`?

Comment: I think it's some of default binding because it was generated by visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer - right URI is:
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/
(without "mex" at the end).